# how to send request through web service proxy as a single packet (don't chunk)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, proxy, packets

I'm trying to utilize a web service through C#.
In the web service documentation it states that the web service only accepts requests as a single packet/stream and not multiple packets.

Does anyone know how to change this setting when accessing the web service through a web reference in Visual Studio?

I am getting a SOAPException "Unable to parse the incoming request" error when I send a request and I assume this is why.

Thanks for your help!

-Steve

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? It pays to say.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be trivial, but it won't be too difficult, either (assuming you've correctly identified the problem). See [Ways to Customize your ASMX Client Proxy](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!435.entry). In the "Heavy Duty Customization" section, you'll see how to override the `GetWebRequest` method of your proxy class by using a partial class. Assuming that your web reference name is "Service1Proxy":

```
public partial class Service1Proxy 
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        request.SendChunked = false;
        return request;
    }
}
```

I recommend you try this, but I also recommend you set a breakpoint after the call to the base `GetWebRequest` method. Check to see if the original request had the `SendChunked` flag set or cleared.